# Open facebook share dialog in a new tab

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the facebook javascript sdk to share an url, and I have this code to make that

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'share',
  href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
}, function(response){});
```

But now I need to open the dialog in a new tab (or if it is impossible, open in the same tab)

Thanks!

Comment: it will open in a new tab only, tell me how it is opening?

Comment: I mean, no in a pop up, instead I want to open in a different page, you understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the delay, the facebook share plugin link have an attribute `display` which you can change to `popup", "dialog", "iframe", "touch", "async", "hidden", or "none"`

> **Check this jsfiddle for opening the link in new tab** :
>
> [Opening Fb share in new tab](https://jsfiddle.net/bhansa/EYxTJ/2566/)

Also read the documentation here:
[Facebook share plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog)

See the live example here:
[Share Plugin Example](http://www.fbrell.com/saved/2779dc018c325d85d650a3b723239650)

Comment: in the above example which I have provided, I have just change the `target` of the window to `_blank`

Comment: see the display option in the given link and also check the example.

Comment: Finally, I use "wap" as display, in the URL Redirection and works. Thanks!